# Docker stops responding after I run a java program inside it

Tags: java, docker

I have a Docker instance on top of Ubuntu:14.04. I have installed the java and everything. Now I am running a simple "HelloWorld.java" code inside the container.

I am using

```
docker run -it --cpuset-mems="0" mt-docking-engine /bin/bash
```

to get inside the container. Once, I am inside I can do many things. But as soon as I run the "HelloWorld.java" program using

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

It gives me "Hello, World!" output (so far so good). But then it gets stuck. I can't even exit from inside the docker normally as I do (by CTRL + C). Nothing works.

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So instead of answering or telling me what is wrong, people just love to down vote.

Comment: Some day StackOverflow may require that a downvote include a comment., but until then don't let downvotes get you down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is: I had to add `System.exit(0);` at the end of the code which was mentioned nowhere. This is how the Java App exits inside the Docker container unlike other c cpp programs that do not need the exit code.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. There are many existing Java programs that don't end in `System.exit(0)`, and many of them are used in Docker builds. I don't think developers have been adding `exit` to existing programs and recompiling them just to get them working on Docker.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `System.exit(0)` . Something is different about your image, settings, or compiler:

I ran this:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

Then:

```
$ docker run -ti --cpuset-mems="0" centos:7 /bin/bash
[root@eddd649c8b96 ~]# javac HelloWorld.java
[root@eddd649c8b96 ~]# java -cp . HelloWorld
Hello, World
[root@eddd649c8b96 ~]# exit
```

Comment: I don't know then. The problem is something else. But System.exit(0) worked for me. As if it needed a 'force' exit or something.